# Why does this inequality hold for smallest positive non-square modulo p?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, finite-fields

Let $p$ be an odd prime and $q$ the smallest positive integer that is not a square modulo $p$. Show that $q<\sqrt{p}+1$?

I can show that $q$ also has to be prime and that $p$ is a divisor of $q^\frac{p-1}{2}+1$. But I am not sure how this can help me.

Comment: Are you sure the problem is stated correctly?  By https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2009/08/18/the-least-quadratic-nonresidue-and-the-square-root-barrier/ it doesn't look like there's a relatively elementary method that gives a $\sqrt{p}+1$ bound...

Comment: There is an elementary argument, see here https://number.subwiki.org/wiki/Smallest_quadratic_nonresidue_is_less_than_square_root_plus_one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume $q>\sqrt p+1$. Let $a=\left\lceil\frac pq\right\rceil$. Then 
 $$1\le a\le\left\lceil\frac p{\sqrt p+1}\right\rceil
=\left\lceil\sqrt p-1+\frac 1{\sqrt p+1}\right\rceil\le\left\lceil\sqrt p\right\rceil<q,$$
hence $a$ is a square $\bmod p$ and so $aq$ is a non-square.
But
from $p\le aq<p+q$, we see that $aq\bmod p$ is one of  $0,1,\ldots,q-1$, hence a square, contradiction.